# I have a buffer overflow assignment like this, I set the correct varaible to the HEX value of 1 (31) and still nothing, how do I solve this

Tags: c, buffer, exploit

How do I set the value of correct to 1 with an buffer overflow exploit?
When I pass nothing to this the value of temper is 4D2 which is hex for 1234, but when I overflow the buffer with lets say 10 A's followed by 1234 -> AAAAAAAAAA1234 temper gets changed to 0x34333231, I don't understand this, can somebody help?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 volatile int correct = 0;
 volatile int tamper = 1234;
 char buffer[10];

 gets(buffer);

 if(strcmp(buffer, [REDACTED])==0) {
   correct = 1;
 }

 if(tamper!=1234) {
     printf("Alert! You hit the tamper switch!\n\n<!--correct = 0x%08x-->\n<!--tamper = 0x%08x-->\n", correct, tamper);
     exit(0);
 }

 if(correct==1) {
  printf("Login successful.\n\n<b>flag{REDACTED}</b>\n\nThe credentials to access this machine are \n\n<b>user:</b>REDACTED\n<b>password:</b>REDACTED\n");

 } else {
  printf("Sorry, password incorrect.\n\n<!--correct = 0x%08x-->\n<!--tamper = 0x%08x-->\n", correct, tamper);
 }

}
```

Comment: Hint: `'1' == 0x31`

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Yeah when I pass a payload with stuff like 0x31 all individual characters get interpreted on their own e.g. 0x31 = 31337830

Answer (score 0):

To exploit this program (if it's an assignment it will surely be compilated corretly to have `buffer` before `correct`) you need to overwrite correct with the `int` value 1.

The hex value of 1 is `0x1`, the hex value of 1234 is `0x4D2`

The structure of the stack will have to be:

```
        ________________
       |                |
       |      0x1       |  correct (sizeof(int) = 4)
       |                |
       |________________|
       |                |
       |     0x4D2      |  tamper (sizeof(int) = 4)
       |                |
       |________________|
       |                |
       |                |
       |                |
       |                |
       |    gibberish   |  buffer (10 * sizeof(char) = 10)
       |                |
       |                |
       |                |
       |                |
       |________________|
       |                |
       ..................
       ..................
       ..................
```

Unfortunately you will have to be aware of endianness, too: `0x1` will be in memory as `0x01000000` (x-86 architectures) or `0x0100000000000000`(x-86_64 architectures). The same will be applied to `tamper`.

**NB**: If you don't want to convert indianness yourself you can just use functions `p32` or `p64` in `pwntools` library

Also notice that a lot of values inside the `tamper` and `correct` will be non-printable.